# kpm restore on Centos 6.5 output is garbled

Tags: .net, centos6, xterm

Running kpm restore on Centos 6.5 returns garbled output:

```
$ kpm restore
Restoring packages for %?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m/vagrant/project.json%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m
Attempting to resolve dependency %?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;mvagrant%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m >= 1.0.0
Attempting to resolve dependency %?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;mMicrosoft.AspNet.Mvc%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m >= 6.0.0
Attempting to resolve dependency %?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;mNowin.vNext%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m >=
Attempting to resolve dependency %?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;mKestrel%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m >= 1.0.0
Attempting to resolve dependency %?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;mmscorlib%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m >=
Attempting to resolve dependency %?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;mSystem%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m >=
Attempting to resolve dependency %?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;mSystem.Core%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m >=
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue related to TTY colors, it was fixed by trying a different TERM with less colors (mine was xterm-256color):

```
$ export TERM=xterm-color
```